# How to install mysql on ubuntu with SaltStack

Tags: mysql, salt-stack

I have to write a SLS file to install mysql-server, mysql-client, mysql-common on ubuntu. How do I do it? The following SLS is giving error saying that these packages are unbale to install or update.

```
state1:
 pkg.installed:
  - pkgs:
     - mysql-server
     - mysql-common
     - mysql-client
```

Comment: I want answer from someone. please

Comment: Did you check the `/var/log/salt/minion` log on the minion or tried to install those packages on the server manually to see if you get an error?

Comment: It worked. Since they were already installed, it was failing.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced an issue with mysql-server specifically. On Ubuntu, it's a "meta-package" which just installs the latest version, e.g. mysql-server-5.5. In my case, there was an error with my preconfiguration, and apt marked "mysql-server" as installed, but "mysql-server-5.5" failed. Later calls to apt failed because of the missing "mysql-server-5.5". I removed mysql-server manually, fixed my issue with the preconfiguration, and it worked fine. Here's my code, for your reference:

```
mysql_setup:
  debconf.set:
    - name: mysql-server
    - data:
        'mysql-server/root_password': {'type': 'string', 'value': '{{ pillar['SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] }}'}
        'mysql-server/root_password_again': {'type': 'string', 'value': '{{ pillar['SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] }}'}

mysql-server:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - require:
      - debconf: mysql_setup
```

Answer (score -1):

That isn't how the pkg.installed directive works. You want this:

```
mysql-server:
  pkg.installed

mysql-common
  pkg.installed

mysql-client
   pkg.installed
```